# My angular ng-submit doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm only just learning angular and have made a form. The submit doesn't work though. I've followed the instructions from the codeschool course but it still doesn't work. When I press submit it doesn't actually add it and it doesn't clear the form which I want it to and if I haven't missed something out from the instructions it should have everything it needs for it to work but I'm clearly missing something..

HTML

```
<form name="rateForm" ng-contoller="reviewController as reviewCtrl" ng-submit="reviewCtrl.addRate(rating)">
    <blockquote>
        <b>Film name: {{reviewCtrl.rate.name}}</b>
        <b>Stars: {{reviewCtrl.rate.price}}</b>
    </blockquote>
    <input type="type" class="film" ng-model="reviewCtrl.rate.name"></input>
    <select ng-model="reviewCtrl.rate.price">
        <option value="1">1 star</option>
        <option value="2">2 star</option>
        <option value="3">3 star</option>
        <option value="4">4 star</option>
        <option value="5">5 star</option>
    </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form >
```

JS

```
(function() {
 var app = angular.module('ratingStore', []);



app.contoller("reviewController", function(){

this.rate = {};
this.addRate = function(rating){
    rating.rate.push(this.rate)
    this.rate = {};
};
 })



})();
```

Comment: It might not. What's your rating that is the arguement for submit function. Where is that defined or captured.

Comment: Your controller needs a $scope. Bindings to the HTML are through the $scope.

Comment: I've done the course on codeschool which doesn't show that you need $scope. Could you possibly show me how it's meant to look?

Comment: @Naomi look at this working sample https://plnkr.co/edit/T5NUPmf6HiyyKotYIWqf?p=preview

Comment: Where are you looking to add the ratings? You should probably use an array for that in you controller

Comment: Your title needs to be much more descriptive than "it doesn't work", Naomi. (You then repeated this phrase twice in the question. Not useful.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, and it was just a typo mistake. He wrote `contOller` instead of `contRoller`.. both in view and in his JS.

Comment: @developer033: That's not what the code in the question says. And, um, "he"?

Comment: _"Change code to first answer"_ Please don't do that. I can't quite tell what's going on with this question, but if you modified the code in the question to match the answer, please revert that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, oh, she.. are you talking with me in this 2nd. comment??? If so, I didn't change any question here o.O All the edits were made by the author. Also, the accepted answer is completely incorrect, the problem isn't with the injection of `$scope`. Angular works very well without this injection. The problem, as I said, is with the keyword `CONTOLLER` instead of `CONTROLLER`.

Comment: @developer033: No, I was not talking to you. But since you've brought it up again, where do you see the keyword "contoller" in the question?

Comment: Here `ng-contoller="reviewController as reviewCtrl" // ` and here: `app.contoller("reviewController", function(){`. By the way, I saw now the last edit in this question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't need to inject `$scope` or anything else. The problem is only one: you wrote **CONTOLLER** instead of **CONTROLLER** both in view and in your JS.

Here's a **demo** *working*:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('ratingStore', [])
    .controller("reviewController", function() {
      this.rate = {};
      this.rating = [];
      
      this.addRate = function() {
        this.rating.push(this.rate);
        this.rate = {};
      }
    });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ratingStore">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="reviewController as reviewCtrl">
  <form name="rateForm" ng-submit="reviewCtrl.addRate()">
    <blockquote>
      <b>Film name: {{reviewCtrl.rate.name}}</b>
      <b>Stars: {{reviewCtrl.rate.price}}</b>
    </blockquote>
    <input type="type" class="film" ng-model="reviewCtrl.rate.name">
    <select ng-model="reviewCtrl.rate.price">
      <option value="1">1 star</option>
      <option value="2">2 star</option>
      <option value="3">3 star</option>
      <option value="4">4 star</option>
      <option value="5">5 star</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <hr> Rating array:
  <pre ng-bind="reviewCtrl.rating | json"></pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace ng-submit function call to form tag from submit button.
Please check the spelling of controller .

Comment: I don't understand how you mean. Could you write it out please?

Comment: @Naomi user286852 is saying to move the `ng-submit` directive from your `<input type="submit"...>` element to your `<form>` element. `ng-submit` is only valid on a `<form>` element.

Comment: I've done that but it still isn't working.

Comment: Please check the spelling of controller

Answer (score 0):

(i) As 'user286852' mentioned you need to add the ng-submit inside the form otherwise, add a button for the submit function and call it in ng-click event.

(ii)You need to defined the $scope variable for ratings to be stored.

```
   $scope.rate = {};
   $scope.rating = [];
   $scope.rating.rate = [];
   $scope.addRate = function() {
   $scope.rating.rate.push($scope.rate)
   console.log($scope.rating.rate);
   $scope.rate = {};
  };
```

Here is the working [`Rating App`](https://plnkr.co/edit/T5NUPmf6HiyyKotYIWqf?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry, but I have to go ahead and say: Although your comment about `ngSubmit` is correct, there's no necessity for the use of `$scope` since the OP is using `controller-as-syntax`.

Answer (score -2):

Where are you taking that rating argument from ? I suppose it is just a ng-model var that stores all ratings, so I'm taking it off as argument and using it as part of $scope. If I'm wrong, just fix this part. 
Now, Instead of using the add rate function as method of control, couldn't you use it as method of $scope ?
Like:
JS:

```
var app = angular.module('ratingStore', []);
app.contoller("reviewController", function($scope){

    $scope.rate = {};
    $scope.addRate = function(){
        $scope.rating.rate.push($scope.rate)
        $scope.rate = {};
    };

}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="rateForm" ng-contoller="reviewController" ng-submit="addRate()">
    <blockquote>
        <b>Film name: {{rate.name}}</b>
        <b>Stars: {{rate.price}}</b>
    </blockquote>
    <input type="type" class="film" ng-model="rate.name"></input>
    <select ng-model="rate.price">
        <option value="1">1 star</option>
        <option value="2">2 star</option>
        <option value="3">3 star</option>
        <option value="4">4 star</option>
        <option value="5">5 star</option>
    </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form >
```

And, don't forgent to call the function where you placed your controller and module.